# Node JS/Express 301 redirect from non www to www domain name

Tags: express, redirect, heroku

I have an application (Node JS/Express) hosted on Heroku that resolves fine using `www`, but when trying to access via https://richlew.co.uk/ or richlew.co.uk I cannot access my site. (The site mentioned is being used for testing purposes only, once resolved I can apply to production site).

Is there anything I can do server side to redirect non www to www? or does this need to be done at DNS level? I have tried setting `ALIAS` and going through the Heroku docs, not getting anywhere.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The reverse is currently in vogue: traffic from www to this one without. `Express` applications do not like double domain names.

But going to the bottom of the topic: such redirections should be implemented by the web server.

You have to change redirect places.
https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/redirect-heroku/